# url is changing but not view in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

> Following is my App component

```
                <BrowserRouter>
                    
                    {/* on top of all the pages */}
                    <Nav/>

                    <Switch>

                        <Route path="/profile">
                            <HostingFormProfile/>
                            <Footer/>
                        </Route>
                        
                        <Route path="/hosting">
                            <Hosting/>
                        </Route>
                        
                        <Route path="/">
                            <Home/>
                            <Footer/>
                        </Route>

                    </Switch>                        

                </BrowserRouter>
```

> Following is my Hosting component

```
      <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/hosting/map">
                    <div className="hosting__map">
                        <Map
                            google={props.google}
                            center={{lat: lat, lng: lng}}
                            height='300px'
                            zoom={15}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/hosting/form">     
                    <HostingForm/>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/hosting">
                    <HostMain/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
      <BrowserRouter>
```

> Now when I am in 'HostingForm' (url "/hosting/form") or 'Map' (url "/hosting/map") component & do
> "history.push("/hosting"); "
> then only url is changed not view.
> How to resolve this issue?

Comment: First of all I should mention that in `HostingComponent`, you shouldn't use `/hosting` at start of paths. because it gets from parent's route. now, your route is like: `/hosting/hosting/...`

Comment: not working, when I do history.push('/hosting') from 'HostingForm' (url "/hosting/form") or 'Map' (url "/hosting/map") then only url is changed  not view & i want to display 'HostMain' component (url "/hosting")

Comment: Did you see [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try wrapping your `<Hosting>` component with `withRouter`.

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router"
.
.
.
export default withRouter(Hosting)
```

Comment: try but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in app component.

```
       <Route path="/hosting/*">
          <Hosting/>
       </Route>
```